# Windows Remote Desktop slows down within a day

Tags: windows, remote-desktop

We have a beefy Windows 10 Enterprise PC with 128GB RAM, 20 Core CPU and 4 GPUs which is being used through remote desktop.

After a restart it is as fast as you expect it to be, but in a matter of 24 hours it slows down consistently, to the point where it takes a couple of seconds to see the text you type appear on your screen. This occurs even when the RAM/CPU usage is below 25%.

There are just a handful of users, at most 5 simultaneously, using the PC through a remote desktop.

We now have to restart the PC every day, which is rather inconvenient.

What could be the cause of the beefy PC slowing down within a matter 24 hours?

Comment: How's the disk IO pressure, I assume you're running SSD and not an HDD. Also check for the Ethernet pressure as a bottleneck. Consider not allowing disconnected sessions and ensuring when they switch users, it logs the other sessions off rather than leaving then disconnected, etc. Since Windows 10 is not really meant for multi-user RDP (like a terminal server), I assume you are not running multiple concurrent 5 users via RDP a the same time using RDPWrapper, etc. You might also check that hibernate is disabled and let Windows manage paging automatically.

Comment: Windows 10 is not meant to multitask. You should consider using Windows Server with the appropriate CAL license, or ask people to sign out when they're done.

Comment: I agree with LPChip - workstations are usually a poor substitute for a proper Server, even for 5 users.

Comment: @VomitIT-ChunkyMessStyle There are in fact multiple users connected to the PC via RDP, at most 5 at the same time.

Comment: @LPChip Will look into Windows Server, at first glance it looks like appropriate OS for multiple concurrent users.

Comment: I run Windows Server to accommodate for just one RDP session because that is just the best way to do it. In fact, this post is written from such environment. RDP to a Windows Server is a better experience, than RDP to a windows 10 desktop. One or Two users don't even need a CAL license.